# Como preencher nulo com valor da linha anterior?

Tags: mysql, query

Olhando para a seguinte tabela, quero preencher o valor que estiver nulo com o valor da linha anterior, qual a melhor de o fazer com mysql?

[image: tabela]

Comment: Relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977267/fill-null-values-with-last-non-null-amount-oracle-sql

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que as linhas estão ordenadas pela coluna cabecalho1, e que esta coluna é numérica e sequencial (sem buracos na numeração):

```
select  cabecalho1, cabecalho2, 
        novoresultado = isnull(cabecalho2,(select cabecalho2 from yourTable where cabecalho1= t.cabecalho1-1))
from yourTable t

--update
update yourTable
set novoresultado = isnull(cabecalho2,(select cabecalho2 from yourTable t where t.cabecalho1 = yourTable.cabecalho1-1))
```

Considerando que as linhas estão ordenadas pela coluna cabecalho1, e que esta coluna é numérica, mas com a possibilidade de existirem números em falta na sequência:

```
select  cabecalho1, cabecalho2, 
        novoresultado = isnull(cabecalho2,(select top 1 cabecalho2 from yourTable where cabecalho1 < t.cabecalho1 order by cabecalho1 desc))
from yourTable t

--update
update yourTable
set novoresultado = isnull(cabecalho2,(select top 1 cabecalho2 from yourTable t where t.cabecalho1 < yourTable.cabecalho1 order by cabecalho1 desc))
```